# JDBC driver for Java 7

Tags: java, jdbc, oracle10g

I want to know that which JDBC driver is suitable for Java 7 i.e. Java Version 1.7.0_01 and for Oracle 10g/11g Database?

Comment: Out of interest, what did you try *before* asking a question here?

Comment: I installed java 1.7 but having database problem so I am asking this.

Comment: The error is >>
`java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver`

Comment: I did all the things...but showing same problem again and again..

Comment: @BahirjiNaik: Then you haven't configured your classpath properly, or you haven't installed the drivers that I've referred you to.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A quick search for "oracle jdbc driver" finds [this page](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/features/jdbc/index-091264.html) on Oracle's website, where you can download the drivers for various versions of Oracle. After selecting a database version, the links take you to a page where you can select the appropriate type of driver to download based on the version of Java you're using - pick the latest one available (even if it only says "for JDK 1.4 and 1.5" or "JDK 1.6").

Comment: ya i know..but which one for Java 1.7.0_01?

Comment: @BahirjiNaik: The one for the latest version of Java shown. The JDK 1.5 drivers will work fine.

Comment: hmmm... then what it means ? J 7 have no drivers for oracle?

Comment: @BahirjiNaik: You don't need *specific* Java 7 drivers - you just use the older version (for JDK 1.4/1.5) and it should work fine.

Comment: Java prides itself on backward compatibility and the older version of the drivers will work on Java 7.

Comment: The latest ones available are for Java 6 btw, they should work fine, unless you try to call one of the new methods added by JDBC 4.1. In general the Oracle 11g drivers will also work for 9i and 10g.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel: Thanks - I'd followed a link to some 10g drivers which didn't include the JDK 1.6 ones. Will edit.

Comment: I can't recommend JDBC drivers that don't explicitly support the JDK that you're using.  Hopefully Oracle's support for Java is better then Microsoft's, but we just ran into a couple issues with Microsoft's JDBC driver on later versions of JDK 1.6 and JDK 1.7.

Comment: @BrianKnoblauch: I strongly suspect that's the exception rather than the rule though - do you apply the same rules for every other third party library you might want to use? Obviously you should test thoroughly, but I think it's reasonable to start with an *expectation* that they should work.

Comment: I am also facing the same problem... I am using jdk-7 and Oracle 10g XE.... I tried ojdbc6.jar and ojdbc14.jar..... but none of the worked.... please let me know which ojdbc driver to use in my case.

Comment: @mav3n: I'm afraid I know no more than what's in my answer. I suggest you ask a new question with *details* of the error.

Answer (score 1):

"Java prides itself on backward compatibility and the older version of the drivers will work on Java 7."

> The use of term "backward compatibility" in this case is just wrong, as the driver for Java 1.7 would be compatible with Java 1.6, but not the other way round.

Anyhow, the implementation of new features of Java 1.7 such as java.sql.Connection implementing AutoCloseable (new interface in 1.7), I would expect a suitable Driver.

Comment: it doesn't necessarily mean java 1.7 will work for 1.6 drivers